# Oracle SQL how to find out which table has the following two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know of a statement that I can issue to find out the table with the column I am looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(table_name)
  FROM all_tab_cols 
 WHERE column_name = 'EMP_ID';
```

However, how should I modify this so that I may find the table that has both say `EMP_ID` and `EMP_NAME`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT table_name
    FROM all_tab_cols 
   WHERE column_name IN ('EMP_ID', 'EMP_NAME')
GROUP BY table_name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) = 2
```

The count comparison must equal the number of parameters defined in the `IN` clause.

...but this is a safer means of determining the table in case their are duplicates:

```
  SELECT table_name
    FROM all_tab_cols 
   WHERE column_name IN ('EMP_ID', 'EMP_NAME')
GROUP BY table_name, owner
  HAVING COUNT(column_name) = 2
```

Comment: in this you have to take 'owner' condition also...

else it would give wrong ans...

Comment: in all big project you have to work in different different schema and that's why i asked you to put owner condition here as well.... okay say in one schema test_1 table has a column name EMP_ID but not having EMP_NAME, and in other schema it has only EMP_NAME.... just think about this also.. this query will give test_1 also.. :)

Comment: I agree with pratik garg, and also the DISTINCT is unnecessary when you've added the owner.

Comment: NOTE THAT You could replace the IN with = and an OR clause, but generalizing this to like may not work because the like could get more than 1 count per term:  e.g.   SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, count(DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME) as ourCount
    FROM all_tab_cols 
   WHERE ( 
   (column_name LIKE '%ID%') OR (COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%NUM%') 
   )
GROUP BY OWNER, TABLE_NAME
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) = 2
   ORDER BY OWNER, TABLE_NAME
 ;

Comment: If interested, see also my question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804657/oracle-sql-syntax-to-find-table-with-two-columns-with-names-like-id-num?noredirect=1&lq=1  This generalizes the question so that "LIKE" can be used for two columns.